# Convert excel tabs to PDF and send in separate emails

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert excel tabs to PDF and send each tab as a single attachment on different emails in outlook with different email recipients.

For example, Tab A would  correspond to a "Vendor Emails" Tab with a To, Cc, and Bcc for each tab. Same would go for Tab B but a different set of recipients.

My Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub create_and_email_pdf()

Dim EmailSubject As String, EmailSignature As String
Dim CurrentMonth As String, DestFolder As String, PDFFile As String
Dim Email_To As String, Email_CC As String, Email_BCC As String
Dim OpenPDFAfterCreating As Boolean, AlwaysOverwritePDF As Boolean, DisplayEmail As Boolean
Dim OverwritePDF As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim OutlookApp As Object, OutlookMail As Object
CurrentMonth = ""

EmailSubject = "Invoice Attached for "
OpenPDFAfterCreating = True
AlwaysOverwritePDF = False
DisplayEmail = True
Email_To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor Emails").Range("B2").Value
Email_CC = ""
Email_BCC = ""


'Prompt for file destination
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If .Show = True Then

        DestFolder = .SelectedItems(1)

    Else

        MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"

        Exit Sub

    End If

End With

'Current month/year
CurrentMonth = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor Emails").Range("E1").Value, InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vendor Emails").Range("E1").Value, " ") + 1)

'Create new PDF file name including path and file extension
PDFFile = DestFolder & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveSheet.Name _
            & "-" & CurrentMonth & ".pdf"

'If the PDF already exists
If Len(Dir(PDFFile)) > 0 Then

    If AlwaysOverwritePDF = False Then

        OverwritePDF = MsgBox(PDFFile & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")

        On Error Resume Next
        'If you want to overwrite the file then delete the current one
        If OverwritePDF = vbYes Then

            Kill PDFFile

        Else

            MsgBox "OK then, if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"

            Exit Sub

        End If

    Else

        On Error Resume Next
        Kill PDFFile

    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"

        Exit Sub

    End If

End If


'Create the PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating

'Create an Outlook object and new mail message
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

'Display email and specify To, Subject, etc
With OutlookMail

    .Display
    .To = Email_To
    .CC = Email_CC
    .BCC = Email_BCC
    .Subject = EmailSubject & CurrentMonth
    .Attachments.Add PDFFile

    If DisplayEmail = False Then

        .Send

    End If

End With


End Sub
```

I keep having an issue with this line, I keep getting a run-time 1004 and that the file may be open/error while saving:

```
'Create the PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating
```

If I don't use the reference ThisWookbook.Sheets(), I dont get an issue, but it only sends out the tab that I'm currently active on, not sure how to specify which tabs to convert.

For more context these tabs I'm converting would be part of a bigger worksheet with additional backup tabs that would not get sent as they are for internal purposes.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to refer to the workbook, not the worksheet, as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-exportasfixedformat-method-excel).

Comment: @Ash that would create a single PDF of all tabs, the OP want to _send each tab as a single attachment on different emails_

Comment: You will have to loop through the Tabs that you want to export as pdf. Since you hve more Tabs than you want to export you need to decide how you will select which worksheet you want. `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` will only save the worksheet that was active when you initiated your macro.

Comment: What about grouping the tabs before I run the macro?

Comment: @GMalc What would i use instead of ActiveSheet then? Is this where I would define which sheets get created as an individual PDF?

Comment: Please review this SO question [Dynamic saving to PDF only certain Sheets in Excel VBA based on sheetname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590841/dynamic-saving-to-pdf-only-certain-sheets-in-excel-vba-based-on-sheetname). For more examples do a Google search for "excel vba loop through specific worksheet and save as pdf"